# fay Could not find module `Control.Applicative'

Tags: fay

foo.hs

```
 import Control.Applicative
```

then

```
 fay foo.hs
```

returns

```
Could not find module `Control.Applicative'
It is a member of the hidden package `base'.
Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Is applicative programming possible in Fay?

Answer (score 0):

Fay doesn't have type classes. We figured that in case someone wants to use an applicative they can implement the operators monomorphically. This would lead to name clashes if we provided some default applicative.

See [this wiki page](https://github.com/faylang/fay/wiki/Why-fay-does-not-currently-support-type-classes) for more info on the status of type class support.

Comment: Is there any way we can talk? I'm about to embark on writing a non-trivial client side application, and would love to do it in haskell. But its gotten more and more confusing out there, as no one seems to be willing to talk about production readyness.